# Which attributes does DPAPI's "UseMachineProtection" use to identify a machine?

Tags: file-encryption, .net, windows-dpapi

We're using `DPAPIProtectedConfigurationProvider` from the Windows Data Protection API to encrypt an application config file. The API offers a property called `UseMachineProtection`, so that the config file is bound to one specific machine.

Which attributes of the machine are used to determine this? For example, if it was just the MAC address of the machine, would that mean the config would become unreadable once the MAC address changes?

Comment: You seem to be asking two different things: "Why does the file become unreadable?" and "What attributes of the machine is `UseMachineProtection` validated against?" Is this correct?

Comment: Hi @MechMK1 No I only want to know the attributes of the machine which usemachineprotection encrypts against. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I suggested an edit for your question to reflect this. I hope this reflects the question better.

Comment: It's rather simple: each machine generates its own encryption key so it's by design not a portable scheme.

Comment: @Steve Unless, of course, you would copy the encryption key.

Comment: thanks @Steve. Do you know how the encryption key is generated though. Going back to my example, will changing the MAC address make the encryption key invalid?

Comment: There's a hierarchy to the keys. You generate a master secret, which is just from the CSPRNG, and then a derived secret is generated from that. Nothing special about the system is fed into this process from Windows' perspective.